# Only displaying background/cursor after login after Natty upgrade (using NVIDIA drivers)

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

I just upgraded to 11.04. Now, after I log in all I get is the background and a cursor (which I can move, no panel, no desktop icons, etc.). Same thing happens if I select classic mode. I tried installing nvidia 173 drivers (instead of nvidia-current) and after that classic mode works again. However I don't want to be using so old graphics drivers (and I'd really like to try out Unity).

My machine is a Dell Precision M65 laptop which contains a GeForce 350M graphics card.

I'm not sure where to start looking for problems, as I'm only guessing that this is a graphics driver problem (usually a pretty solid guess). Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/728745) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an open bug: [bug description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/728745)